# Send date to a react datepicker - Selenium C# Automation

Tags: c#, selenium, ui-automation, react-datepicker

I am having trouble sending a date to a react-date picker. I can send it to the element/input box but value disappears if I click on another element on the page. I am trying to avoid of going through the date picker. Is there a way that I can send or set the value?

//element

```
  private By Element_input(string _question, string element = "1") { return 
  By.XPath(string.Format("//*[contains(text(),'{0}')]/following::input[{1}]", _question, 
  element)); }
```

//send method

```
    SendKey_javaExecutor(Element_input("What is the Inception date?"), "10/01/2022");
```

//send action

```
    protected void SendKey_javaExecutor(By locator, string text)
    {
        IWebElement SplitCaseYes = _driver.FindElement(locator);
        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + text + "';", SplitCaseYes);
    }
```

[image: html snnipet]

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: Have you tried to use the `.SendKeys` method? TAB > type the data > TAB again.

Comment: No, I have not tried it. Let me try it. Thank you